# Cómo organizar fecha de un arreglo de mayor a menjor y sin fechas repetidas

Tags: javascript, json, array, jsonobject

```
 var datos = [
  0: {fechas: "2018-11-01", registros: 0}
  1: {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0}
  2: {fechas: "2018-10-27", registros: 0}
  3: {fechas: "2018-10-28", registros: 0}
  4: {fechas: "2018-10-29", registros: 0}
  5: {fechas: "2018-10-30", registros: 0}
  6: {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 8}
  7: {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 0}
 ]
```

La idea es que queden en orden de fechas, es decir de mayor a menor y que se elimininen los repetidos con 0 registros en este caso se eliminaria el "2018-10-31" y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
var datos = [
  0: {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0}
  1: {fechas: "2018-10-27", registros: 0}
  2: {fechas: "2018-10-28", registros: 0}
  3: {fechas: "2018-10-29", registros: 0}
  4: {fechas: "2018-10-30", registros: 0}
  5: {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 8}
  6: {fechas: "2018-11-01", registros: 0}
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta solución creo que funciona bien.

```
var datos = [
    {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-11-01", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-27", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-26", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-29", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-28", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 8},
    {fechas: "2018-10-30", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-11-01", registros: 0},
    {fechas: "2018-10-31", registros: 0}
];

//Eliminar repetidos
for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){

    for (let j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {

        if (j != i){
            if (datos[i].fechas.indexOf(datos[j].fechas) != -1) {
                datos.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Ordenar ascendente
for (let i = 1; i < datos.length; i++){

    for (let j = 0; j < datos.length - i; j++){

        if (datos[j].fechas > datos[j + 1].fechas){

            let aux = datos[j+1].fechas;
            datos[j+1].fechas = datos[j].fechas;
            datos[j].fechas = aux;
        }
    }
}

//Otra forma de ordenar usando el método sort() de javascript
//datos.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.fechas) - new Date(b.fechas));

console.log(datos);
```